# Using undeclared list as argument in c++

Tags: c++

Started learning C++ recently by completing checkio.org 'missions'. My main problem now is validating solutions, so I thought of using assert() like so:

```
assert(index_power({1, 2, 3, 4}, 2) == 9);
```

Problem is I always get error saying:

```
error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int index_power(int*, int)’  
assert(index_power({1, 2, 3, 4}, 2) == 9);
```

Is there a way to pass undeclared array as function argument or do I have to declare new array every time I want to use assert like this??

Comment: `int index_power(int*, int)` use a `int index_power(std::vector<int>, int)` signature instead.

Comment: You need to overload the function (that initializer list is of different type from arrays.

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ said , you need a `std::vector` , rather than a raw pointer. Or some other library that supports `std::initializer_list` such as `std::list` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here you currently have a braced-enclosed initalizer list:

```
assert(index_power({1, 2, 3, 4}, 2) == 9);
```

the list being : `{1, 2, 3, 4}` . To allow this brace-enclosed initializer list you need to use libraries that allow this method. Such as the `std::vector`. So you can change your argument:

```
int index_power(int* args, int num);
```

to

```
int index_power(std::vector<int>, int num);
```

If you are interested how you can make a custom braced-enclosed initializer constructor you can use `std::initalizer_list`:

```
MyClass(std::initializer_list<int> li) {
  std::vector<int> v(li);
}
```

You can see more about `std::initalizer_list` [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: `std::vector` can be directly initialized with the matching `std::initializer_list`. No need for `v.insert(v.end(), li.begin(), li.end());`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so like `std::vector<T> v(initalizer_list);` ?

Comment: `std::vector<int> v(li);` then.

Comment: Updated Code changes